# loading url from json data without any delay

Tags: json, url, loading, preload

I am loading a url from the json data in the webview tag.As of now I have included the loading icon when there is delay in the loading of the url but I do not want to load the page with any loading spinner.Instead I want to preload the json data variables so that there is no delay in displaying the url page.Is there any way I can do this.?

Comment: you're loading them via AJAX I guess? If you want to pre-load them then you'd have to have a server-side script which makes the request to that other URL, gets the data and then injects the results into your HTML. But if that URL takes time to respond, it will just slow down the overall loading of your page instead, so I'm not sure you really gain anything.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. IMO the way you've got it now is better for the user because a) they can see the rest of your page while that data is loading, and b) they can see a loading indicator so they know there is some delay. Whereas if all they've got is an empty browser window with the browser waiting for the server to load the whole page (which is what you'd have in the alternative scenario I described) then it's a lot less user-friendly.

Comment: Actually my Json data looks like this {

"notification" : {
"title" : "Notification",
"body" : "Your Notification.",
"click_action" : "https://www.google.com"

},
"data" : {
"Date" : "Aug 02, 2018",

 "setting_url": "https://ww.google.com"
}
}   I am obtaining the Url from click_action and then displaying it in webview tag.But the url takes time to display .I want to preload it before showing it in webview tag

Comment: if the remote server is slow to respond, there's not much you can do about it. You have to wait. The only way to "preload" anything is server-side, the way I described.